# javascript / jquery / processing.js - how to most effectively create and animate canvas elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, processing, processing.js

I'm trying to build an application which, based on various user interactions, allows for various ellipse based visuals to be added to the stage and then animated very simply. I've currently got a basic demo set up where javascript / jquery communicates with processing.js, but it just seems like really inefficient code, because processing relies on running a continuous loop in order to draw to the screen. I'm wondering, one, if the way I'm doing it will be effective on a larger scale, and two, if there's a better technology or method to use. I come from a flash background where nothing on screen is changed or drawn/animated unless a function is triggered telling it to animate, which seems sensible. Anyway, here's my code:

HTML / JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Processing</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/processing-1.3.6.min.js"></script>
        <script src="processing/Tween.lib"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <canvas id="circles" data-processing-sources="js/drawCircles.js"></canvas>
        <div id="clicker">Click</div>
        <script>

        window.Processing.data = {};

        var dataRef = window.Processing.data;
        var animInterval;
        dataRef.circleArray = new Array();


        $('#clicker').click(function(){
            var circle = {};
            circle.radius = 50;
            dataRef.circleArray.push(circle)
            var from = {property: 50};
            var to = {property: 75};

            jQuery(from).animate(to, {
                duration: 300,
                step: function() {
                    for (var i in dataRef.circleArray){
                        circle.radius = this.property;
                    }
                }
            });
        })

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

PROCESSING.JS

```
// Global variables
float radius = 1.0;
int X, Y;
int nX, nY;
int delay = 16;

// Setup the Processing Canvas
void setup(){
    // Fill canvas grey
    background( 100 );
    size( 200, 200 );
    strokeWeight( 10 );
    frameRate( 15 );
    X = width / 2;
    Y = width / 2;
    nX = X;
    nY = Y;  
}

// Main draw loop
void draw(){
    var dataRef = window.Processing.data;
    for (var i in window.Processing.data.circleArray){
        radius = dataRef.circleArray[i].radius;
        // Set fill-color to blue
        fill( 0, 121, 184 );
        // Set stroke-color white
        stroke(255); 
        // Draw circle
        ellipse( X+(i*10), Y, radius, radius );
    }          
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at more straightforward canvas libraries, like [fabric.js](http://kangax.github.com/fabric.js/)? Fabric gives you an object model to work with objects on canvas (+animation, svg parsing, and more). And it's all JS, so no need to learn new syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to control when Processing.js draws to the canvas, you have two options. In both cases, the first thing you'll want to do is get access to the Processing instance:

```
var p = Processing.instances[0];
```

Now you can make all the Processing API calls you want from JavaScript. You could call noLoop() in your sketch's setup() function, and then inside your jQuery animation loop you could call p.redraw(), which will animate one frame.

In Processing.js we attach all of the functions to the Processing instance. So another option is creating your own function in the sketch, and call it with:

```
var p = Processing.instances[0];
p.drawEllipses(radius);
```

You could even pass the data to it in the function parameters, removing the need for windows.Processing.data.

Comment: Thanks - this makes sense, but I can't detect any processing instances using this code. Is there something I need to do within my processing code to make this available?

Comment: That's... bizarre. If I'm running a sketch in the web page, I can open up my console and Processing.instances will return an array of the currently active Processing sketches. If you're still running into problems, come visit us on IRC: irc.mozilla.org #processingjs .

Comment: Thanks - I think the problem was that I was mixing new code with an old instance of processing, otherwise your solution is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For what you want to do, you might prefer using another library such as paperjs http://paperjs.org/

Comment: Yeah I think you're right. I switched to raphael.js - but paperjs is cool too.